# How to send upload file to other website by using curl in php?

Tags: php, curl

How does one upload a file to another website by using Curl in PHP and get the response page?

The website: http://www.postto.me

```
<form action="posttome.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="2097152" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
<input type="file" size="30" class="input" name="img">
<input type="submit" class="input" value="Upload" name="upload">
</form>


<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.postto.me/upload.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // same as <input type="file" name="file_box">
    $post = array(
        "img"=>$_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"],
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;

echo $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
}
?>
```

it not working [How]??

Comment: Have you tried reading the [cURL manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) on PHP.net?

Comment: i don't know how and what, but this worked for me :) The only difference was that i dont upload a file to my server, instead i send a default file to the site

Answer (score 4):

On top of Paul Schreiber's answer:

According to [how to upload file using curl with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php), starting from php 5.5 you need to use `curl_file_create($path)` instead of `"@$path"`.

Tested: it does work.

With the `@` way no file gets uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [example of how to upload a file](http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html). (First hit for "curl file upload example php".)

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, _VIRUS_SCAN_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // same as <input type="file" name="file_box">
    $post = array(
        "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Comment: that working to another website?  "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",
?