# How to upload file to another by using curl and php?

Tags: php, curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('name' => 'img', 'file' => $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"].".png");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.postto.me/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

and Get Response?

Comment: Can you ellaborate a bit more? What is your problem?

Comment: Self dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706311/how-to-send-upload-file-to-other-website-by-using-curl-in-php

Comment: Yes, anybody can perform this request on your server.

Answer (score 3):

sender.php

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
// true to return the transfer as a string of the return value
// of 'curl_exec' instead of outputting it directly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/test/curl/receiver.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
  'euro' => '@eurodance.pls',
  'flush' => '@flush_next.png',
  'first_name' => 'Vadim'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
```

receiver.php

```
if(isset($_FILES)){
  $temp_file_name = $_FILES['euro']['tmp_name'];
  $original_file_name = $_FILES['euro']['name'];

  // Find file extention
  $ext = explode ('.', $original_file_name);
  $ext = $ext [count ($ext) - 1];

  // Remove the extention from the original file name
  $file_name = str_replace ($ext, '', $original_file_name);

  $new_name = '_'.$file_name . $ext;
//echo $file_name ." ". $ext;

  if (move_uploaded_file ($temp_file_name, $new_name)) {
      echo "success";
   } else {
      echo "error";
    }

}
if(isset($_FILES)){
  $temp_file_name = $_FILES['flush']['tmp_name'];
  $original_file_name = $_FILES['flush']['name'];

  // Find file extention
  $ext = explode ('.', $original_file_name);
  $ext = $ext [count ($ext) - 1];

  // Remove the extention from the original file name
  $file_name = str_replace ($ext, '', $original_file_name);

  $new_name = '_'.$file_name . $ext;
//echo $file_name ." ". $ext;

  if (move_uploaded_file ($temp_file_name, $new_name)) {
      echo "success";
   } else {
      echo "error";
    }

}
```

As you can see this support multiple file uploads.