# Upload file from local server to web server using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, codeigniter-2

I have a client database that generates and stores reports on a local server and I would like these reports to be able to be accessed by a publicly accessible remote server.

The local server runs windows, and I am running a unix installation on the remote server.

The public side is built with codeigniter, and the local side is proprietary php code. How would I go about transferring files onto the remote server?

I am not looking for somebody to write the code for me, but if you could provide a general example, or point me in the right directon it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this can give you some idea - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/

Comment: I already have the files uploaded on the local server. I guess my question is more of "How do I move the file to the remote server?". I don't need to have any javascript interaction, this should all happen in the background.

Comment: if you have access to your remote server, you can use winscp to move all your files to remote server.

Comment: That looks like it will work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing winSCP on my local windows server, then from the php file using shell_exec to call a batch file with commands to transfer the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURL to send file in background to local server to other server, Here is good example.

[How to send upload file to other website by using curl in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706311/how-to-send-upload-file-to-other-website-by-using-curl-in-php)